# How can I align input elements horizontally in rMarkdown flexdashboard

Tags: css, shiny, r-markdown

They appear below each other by default

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny    
---

```{r input}

numericInput(inputId="a",label=NULL,value = 5,min = 1,max = 15)

selectInput(inputId="b",label=NULL,c("x","y","z"))


```
````

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Wrap the elements in an additional div container with id `myGroup` and add CSS styles to the individual child elements:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny    
---

<style>
#myGroup > div {
  width: 45% !important;
  float: left !important;
  margin: 10px !important;
}
</style>

```{r input}
div(numericInput(inputId="a",label=NULL,value = 5,min = 1,max = 15),
selectInput(inputId="b",label=NULL,c("x","y","z")), id='myGroup')
```
````

**Option 2:**

Another option would be to add an individual class to the elements with jQuery:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny    
---

<style>
.myClass {
  width: 45% !important;
  float: left !important;
  margin: 10px !important;
}
</style>

```{r input}
numericInput(inputId="a",label=NULL,value = 5,min = 1,max = 15)
selectInput(inputId="b",label=NULL,c("x","y","z"))
```

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-group').addClass('myClass');
  });
</script>
````

Each input element is contained inside a div container with the class `form-group`. We select these div containers and add the class `myClass` to them, which we have defined above.

[image]

(The part `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` only says that `...` should be executed, when the document is fully loaded.)

Comment: Thanks. This does answer the question posed. However, is it possible to generalize it more so that it covers non-inputs So, for instance if I wanted to replace one of the inputs with some helpText()  which has a class="help-block" can i add that to the script somehow? tx